# Can a Kilonova sterilize a galaxy

Tags: astronomy

I recall [recently reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-Earth_supernova) that a supernova explosion would produce enough radiation to sterilize or severely damage Earth-like worlds within a radius of a dozen or so light-years.

[Kilonovas/Macronova](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07235) of the type recently observed in a galaxy 120 million light years away, as the name suggest, can be up to 1000 times more luminous. Has anybody computed the extinction radius of such a beast?

Comment: Everything I find indicates that kilonovae are much *less* energetic than supernovae - the 'kilo-' compares to novae, which are a very different process than a supernova.

Comment: The linked paper suggests a luminosity of $\sim 10^{33} − 10^{34}$ W, which is  far less than the luminosity of a gamma ray burst ($\sim 3\cdot 10^{42}$ W), although it lasts much longer. Hence the kill radius is much smaller.

Comment: There *was* a GRB, albeit a faint one. But yea,h, a kilonva is less energetic than a Supernova. The GW spectacle before is super cool, though.